# Are KiCad's horizontal 2.54" pin header and 90 degree pin headers equivalent?

Tags: kicad, footprint, pin-headers

I was experimenting with PCB layout in KiCad and noticed that the Connector_PinHeader_2.54mm > PinHeader_1x06_P2.54mm_Horizontal footprint and a physical 90 degree pin header I have do not seem to match, as seen in this photograph:

[image: comparison of KiCad pin header and physical pin header]

The physical pin header in my possession appears to be designed to have the plastic spacer in contact with the PCB, with the other half of the pins used for contact with the female connector.

On the other hand, KiCad's footprint resembles more an upright header laying down on the PCB with a bend to go through the pad further down than most upright headers' pins extend.

I was unable to find anything which resembled the KiCad component through any of the component suppliers I typically use.  Is it a real thing, and does it have a name?  If not, does KiCad have an equivalent to the real component?

Comment: just make a new footprint with the exact model you intend to use. Vendors such as Digikey often link right to the model. Use the STEP file format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [source for the KiCad 3d model generator](https://gitlab.com/kicad/libraries/kicad-packages3D-generator/-/blob/master/Connector_PinHeader/cq_parameters.yaml#L54), these pin headers were modeled using a [WE 613 0xx 110 21](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/6130xx11021.pdf)

You can find them [in stock at Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/61300611021/4846832)

[image: WE Header]

[image: Actual part]

Answer (score 6):

What really matters for the footprint is the pad vs pin spacing.  The 3D image is just a frill - it might be nice if the image matched the actual part you have, but it doesn't really matter. (When I started designing PC boards, no-one even dreamed of having a 3D image of the completed board).

Comment: yep. However, times have changed... the mechanical designers really like the 3D output that is available now, for the specific reason of getting connector-clearance issues right. From that point of view, it is very helpful to use the correct model. The manufacturers make them available in STEP format, which plugs right into KiCad.